# expose an anonymous type to entire asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I expose a variable that has an anonymous type to the entire asp page? I cannot declare the variable in the page class definition because the type needs to be evaluated by the actual assignment. Here it is (currently it is declared in a method):

```
var beforeAndAfterMeds = 
 (from t in adminDB.tbl_patients_clinic_visit_records_medications_before_and_after_visits
  join m in adminDB.tbl_patients_medications on t.MedicationId equals m.PatientMedicationsId_this
  where t.PatientClinicVisitRecordsId == visit.PatientClinicVisitRecordsId_this
  orderby t.SupposedToBeOnPrelist descending, m.MedicationName
  select new { 
    m.MedicationName, 
    t.ZeroForBeforeVisitOneForAfterVisit,
    t.AvailableInGPS,
    t.SupposedToBeOnPrelist })
.ToList();
```

How can I expose this to the entire page so that I can access it from other methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create your own class instead of using an anonymous type.

Comment: Create your own class and  read about to share data beyond local space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use an anonymous type.  Create a new named type to represent this data when you need to expose the information about this type beyond a particular local scope.

Comment: Truly the only sensible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the answer from @Servy but if you really want to do this, you could probably convert the list to a List of Object.

```
return myList.OfType<object>().ToList();
```

Comment: At which point the list becaomes about as useful as a chocolate teapot.

Comment: @Jamiec That seems overly generous.  A chocolate teapot sounds rather tasty right about now.

Comment: @Jamiec mostly yes. Im not condoning it. But it can still be used for in a webforms data binding scenario so not entirely useless